# Python command for Extraction of c++ object

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python

Can someone please tell me python command for extraction of c++ objects in python. i am able to expose this by using boost python but do not know the access command in python. the sample code shows how to expsose c++ objects for python.

```
 BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Test)
  {

  object x_class(
  class_<CTest>("CTest"))
    ;
   object x_obj = x_class();
   CTest& test_obj = extract<CTest&>(x_obj);

  }
```

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible.  The Python/C API allows C and C++ programmers access to the Python interpreter; it does not allow Python programmers access to C and C++.  If you can elaborate on your use case for this, maybe there is an alternative solution that can accomplish your goal.